# NPM Install failing several ENOENTs

Tags: node.js, npm

Found a crypto price tracking bot online, and attempting to get it up and running. I'm on Windows 10, installed node. When I attempt to do `npm install`, I get a slew of errors. package.json is in the directory, so don't think that's an issue. I've tried deleting node_modules, I've also tried `npm init`. Errors listed below -

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\price-bot\node_modules\.staging\readable-stream-c0102ab6\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\price-bot\node_modules\.staging\ws-394827a3\lib\buffer-util.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\price-bot\node_modules\.staging\ws-394827a3\lib\constants.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\price-bot\node_modules\.staging\ws-394827a3\lib\event-target.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\price-bot\node_modules\.staging\ws-394827a3\lib\extension.js'
```

There were a ton in between this too (a total of 319 lines of errors - too many to post here). Then finally the errors finish with this.

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub\price-bot\node_modules\.staging\caniuse-lite-e9bee1b9\data\features.js'
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-24T02_52_37_963Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The warnings are just warnings, they're not a big problem. Making sure npm is up to date and running `npm cache clear -f` and/or `npm cache verify` would likely get the warnings to go away.

The real problem is in your second snippet, which shows that you either don't have Git installed or don't have it in your PATH for npm to use when it needs to install dependencies from repositories. Since you're in a `Github` directory I assume you have Git installed somewhere; if you're going back and forth between git-bash and Powershell/CMD or something like that, you'd need to make sure you have Git in your PATH on both sides.

Comment: thanks so much! that fixed it right up :)